# foreach loop in xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach

I have below XML and need to transform it.

```
XML:<Assessment>
        <Section ID="Listening">24</Section>
        <Section ID="Writing">10</Section>      
        <Section ID="Reading">30</Section>
        <Section ID="ABC">22</Section>
    </Assessment>
```

Output :

```
 Listening-24
 Writing-10
 Reading-30
 ABC-22
```

I have tried below code but I am not able to get score of Assessment in the output.
How can I get value present in Assessment?

XSL:

```
enter code here
<xsl:for-each select="Assessment/Section">
                <xsl:value-of select="@ID"></xsl:value-of>
                <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"></xsl:value-of>
                <xsl:value-of select="Section"></xsl:value-of>
                <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"></xsl:value-of>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Please provide help to fix this code.

Comment: Please post your **entire** stylesheet, with the variables definitions.

Comment: Yes it is . Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:template match="/Assessment">
    <xsl:for-each select="Section">
        <xsl:value-of select="@ID"/>
        <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```